# How to get Office Development Tools in VS Community on Windows 10 64bit?

Tags: .net, vba, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-community, vba6

2 Closely related questions, an explanation that may help find a partial solution for other sufferers if this problem is widespread, and an opportunity for someone to make this better:

1. Is there a better functionality in Office Developer Tools which
   implements a (partial) VBA6 to VBS conversion and provides
   simplified access to Office Applications that can be Used within
   Visual Studio Community?
2. (Now answered) Following my crazy install, described and
   illustrated below, is the resulting development environment likely
   to give the best possible VS usage/learning environment possible? - Thanks to [thunderframe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5757159/thunderframe) it appears that, despite warnings to the contrary from Microsoft, the *..Update 2* does work without the underlying Tools being installed.  A screen grab shows part of the list you see when 'Web Platform Installer' is run.

**BACKGROUND AND PROCESS SO FAR**

I want to convert a large body of working non-profit VBA6 code written in the Office environment to VBS to improve deployment and get better support for code management. Getting started should be easy: install VS Community & start importing your VBA code.  The hard part would be to do the conversions themselves because there is a lot to [consider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192490%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and a lot to [do](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/309617).  This is **NOT** true.  Surprisingly, the huge download that is VS Community does not include the Microsoft Office Developer Tools; locating and installing them does not get you going.

This package: `OfficeToolsForVS2015.exe` is where you'd expect it & downloads from the [Office Developer Tools page for VisualStudio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/office-tools/).  When run it downloads lots more.  But on Windows 10 on a Microsoft Surface Pro 4 64bit computer it fails to load anything that is visible and declares multiple errors.  The error log that it generates are included in the Code block at the bottom of this post.  Nothing shows up in the New Project Window; its list goes from Web to Cloud with no Office/SharePoint entry ...(the screen grabs below which actually show how it looks *after* shows the New Project window after the partial success described later).  Downloading and Installing multiple times in case the download within the install was corrupted gave the same failures, as you might expect.  Online info suggested that the problem might be due to Office not installing everything that it should (though my Microsoft branded PC had a factory installed and activated, fully updated current version of Office 365 '2016' and Windows 10 Pro 64).  Following a full day of massive and glacially slow downloads I had Office fully reinstalled and working.   Running `OfficeToolsForVS2015.exe` again on top of the re-installed Office and following a reboot gave exactly the same result, so did trying it again.  No joy; days wasted.

So, what could be done?  Give up Visual Studio altogether and stick to 1990s style unmanaged code?  I looked around again and found that there is an [update to the Office Developer Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683) but one of the 'Requirements' is that this download should only be installed when Office Developer Tools were already loaded - of course, on my machine they had failed to load.  Well, maybe that is not true, I thought - I was desperate by now, of course.

After downloading Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015 you get this [page congratulating you on your wisdom](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=51683).  You find that there is a large file called : `cba_bundle.exe` on your disk (note, I chose the **enu** version from the unhelpful download page which did not restrict the list to English, even though I had selected 'English' on the preceding web page).  I then installed this new package.  This time, to my great relief, the New Project Window showed the results in the illustration below; from there it has been possible to create VBS projects that link to Office Applications and begin the process of learning Visual Studio.

This is a horrible start with Visual Studio.  After all this, I still don't know if I have a sensible install of the Developer Tools.  Am I missing important components of it that might make learning and use much easier?  Certainly, the VBA6->VBS wizard mentioned in many of Microsoft's Online Articles does not appear.  If VBA6 code is pasted into a Code Window VS does some minor conversions but nothing like the amount of conversion mentioned in discussion of the Wizard.  Perhaps the Wizard is history?   *further research suggests that the Wizard is no longer available.*

It is no longer possible to VS 2005 from Microsoft so you can't work out for yourself whether the older Wizard is worthwhile, even if you wanted to spend all that time trying an earlier obsolete version of VS.
[image: NewProject Dialog after 'Previewer 2' is installed]

In the above, the mouse is hovering over the newly installed Office related template.
[image: Visual Studio New Project Window, showing Office Developer Tools Screen Grab]
The Office/Sharepoint node expands to show the above and the related Templates in the list.

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9842185
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9842185 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 175
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:29:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
Downlo

adManager Information: 0 : Response headers:

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Dec 2016 20:52:28 GMT
ETag: "2324ded08255d21:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=189
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:29:39 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-CCC: GB
X-CID: 2


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1343597488.xml.temp
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID 5nine
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Security
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID 5nine
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Security
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Backup
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Portal
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Backup
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Portal
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Backup
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Resource Provider
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID VMWare
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID VMWare
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID VMWare
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Usage
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Usage
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Usage
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Usage
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Cruiser
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Showback
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Cruiser
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Showback
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Terawe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://aka.ms/webapplicationlist
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://aka.ms/webapplicationlist responded with 301
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: https://webgallery.microsoft.com/feed/webapplicationlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 177
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:29:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive


DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://webgallery.microsoft.com/feed/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
ETag: "084cb974455d21:0"
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=8913756eaae2f9a5f1c9b389b95bc265547f5ef776d5a23ad651a9b8e655f339;Path=/;Domain=webgallery.microsoft.com
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:29:46 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-966730450.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://aka.ms/webapplicationlist' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-966730450.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 May 2014 18:42:31 GMT
ETag: "26a51545ed6acf1:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=243
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:29:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-CCC: GB
X-CID: 2


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-230948881.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/mediaproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-230948881.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/ToolsProductList.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/ToolsProductList.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 19:05:52 GMT
ETag: "9fc99b9fb432d11:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=75
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:29:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-CCC: GB
X-CID: 2


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1135381691.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/ToolsProductList.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-1135381691.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 May 2014 18:42:32 GMT
ETag: "8285645ed6acf1:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=697
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:29:48 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-CCC: GB
X-CID: 2


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1877981721.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-1877981721.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9842185' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\1343597488.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual entry products: OfficeToolsForVS2015
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Microsoft Office Developer Tools Update 2 for Visual Studio 2015 (OfficeToolsForVS2015) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual navigation to product 'OfficeToolsForVS2015'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 203
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:29:49 GMT
Connection: keep-alive


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-Encoding header: 'gzip'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '25178'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '82062'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Error getting last-modified header, error code: 12150
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : HttpQueryInfoWithRetry for HTTP_QUERY_LAST_MODIFIED failed.
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'OfficeToolsForVS2015'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'IdentityExtensionsRTMALLUSERS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WIF
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'HTTPRedirection
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'ServerSideIncludes
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'BasicAuthentication
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WindowsAuthentication
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'DigestAuthentication
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'IISClientCertificateMappingAuthentication
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WASProcessModel
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting IIS 8.0 component install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01D06854-CA0C-46F1-ADBA-EBF86010DCC6/RTM/MicrosoftIdentityExtensions-64.msi' to: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2113.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '258048'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Creating unattended setup file: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2124.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '258048'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting IIS unattended setup: C:\windows\sysnative\dism.exe /Online /Apply-Unattend:"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2124.tmp"
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\IdentityExtensionsRTMALLUSERS\200F72F12A0272F10E04BFD2462DFF11B5E81C4A\MicrosoftIdentityExtensions-64.msi' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2113.tmp' to: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\IdentityExtensionsRTMALLUSERS\200F72F12A0272F10E04BFD2462DFF11B5E81C4A\MicrosoftIdentityExtensions-64.msi
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Waiting for process: 5892 - C:\windows\sysnative\dism.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=780545&clcid=0x409' to: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2163.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=780545&clcid=0x409 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Location: http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/2/622AFFEB-4F02-470F-8273-FBD54ACB6A31/14.0.23928/enu/cba_bundle.exe
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:31:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '73249488'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '73249488'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\OfficeToolsForVS2015\BA2201F715E5AA56899BC7C5C3A6BDB5F78CBA61\cba_bundle.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2163.tmp' to: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\OfficeToolsForVS2015\BA2201F715E5AA56899BC7C5C3A6BDB5F78CBA61\cba_bundle.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
<servicing>
  <package action="configure">
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package" version="10.0.14393.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="AMD64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" versionScope="nonSxS" />
    <selection name="IIS-WebServerRole" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-WebServer" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-CommonHttpFeatures" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-StaticContent" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-DefaultDocument" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-DirectoryBrowsing" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-HttpErrors" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-HttpRedirect" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-WebDAV" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ApplicationDevelopment" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-ASPNET" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-NetFxExtensibility" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ASPNET45" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-NetFxExtensibility45" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ASP" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-CGI" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ISAPIExtensions" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ISAPIFilter" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ServerSideIncludes" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-WebSockets" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ApplicationInit" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-HttpLogging" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-LoggingLibraries" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-RequestMonitor" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-HttpTracing" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-CustomLogging" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ODBCLogging" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-Security" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-BasicAuthentication" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-WindowsAuthentication" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-DigestAuthentication" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-URLAuthorization" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-RequestFiltering" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-IPSecurity" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-CertProvider" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-Performance" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-HttpCompressionStatic" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-WebServerManagementTools" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-ManagementConsole" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ManagementScriptingTools" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-ManagementService" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-Metabase" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-WMICompatibility" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-LegacyScripts" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-LegacySnapIn" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-FTPServer" state="True" />
    <selection name="IIS-FTPSvc" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-FTPExtensibility" state="False" />
    <selection name="IIS-HostableWebCore" state="False" />
    <selection name="WAS-WindowsActivationService" state="True" />
    <selection name="WAS-ProcessModel" state="True" />
    <selection name="WAS-NetFxEnvironment" state="False" />
    <selection name="WAS-ConfigurationAPI" state="False" />
  </package>
</servicing></unattend>
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Unattended setup returned '14081'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: WAS Process Model done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: HTTP Redirection done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Server Side Includes done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 4
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Basic Authentication done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 5
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Windows Authentication done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 6
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Digest Authentication done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 7
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Client Certificate Mapping Authentication done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 8
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Client Certificate Mapping Authentication done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 9
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Identity Foundation'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Identity Foundation had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 10
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Microsoft Identity Extensions'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Identity Extensions had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 11
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Microsoft Office Developer Tools Update 2 for Visual Studio 2015'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Office Developer Tools Update 2 for Visual Studio 2015 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 12
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WASProcessModel, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:10.9550823
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: HTTPRedirection, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:10.9550823
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: ServerSideIncludes, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:10.9550823
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: BasicAuthentication, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:10.9550823
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WindowsAuthentication, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:10.9550823
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: DigestAuthentication, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:10.9550823
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:10.9550823
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: IISClientCertificateMappingAuthentication, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:10.9550823
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WIF, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: IdentityExtensionsRTMALLUSERS, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: OfficeToolsForVS2015, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
```

The `code` above shows the errors declared by the Microsoft Office Developers Tools installation package `OfficeToolsForVS2015.exe` on a Microsoft Surface Pro 4 with Windows 10 64bit and Office 365.

[image: Web Platform Installer 5.0 screen grab]
Above: Answer to Question 2, illustrated by Web Platform Installer 5.0 screen grab following recommendation by [thunderframe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5757159/thunderframe).

Comment: What's in the node if you expand it?

Comment: HAve you tried the offline installer for Office Developer Tools, as described here: http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/downloading-office-developer-tools-for-offline-install-2/

Comment: My understanding is that the Office Developer Tools consists of libraries and templates for the creation of extensions and add-ins for the Microsoft Office applications. I don't believe that it's going to help you update VB6 programs.

Comment: Thanks [Mat's Mug](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mats-mug).  I have added another screen grab to show what the node expands to.  There are fewer entries on the Web Add-Ins entry, basically one per Office  Application.

Comment: Hey [Thunderframe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5757159/thunderframe), that is a great tip as my download speed is glacial (I'm out in the countryside). Running webpicmd.exe in an elevated Administrator command Window is really helpful.  It lists the Microsoft Frameworks and Tools that are already loaded and, better, others that you can access.  (Surprisingly it shows some multiple times - maybe reading from registry?)  Anyway, from that, it looks like I have a good copy of VSTO and of the Developer Tools Update.  Do you know if this information is a reliable indicator of a good install?

Comment: [tlemaster](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7254350/tlemaster): I have VBA6 apps in Office and want to modernise - I recognise that there is conversion work to do to the code (especially with error trapping).  If I do that, do you think that the converted code in VSTO running as an Add-In (as a .dll) will be better and easier to deploy?  The developer tools do seem to link VSTO and the Office Applications.  So far I have only managed to run the example code, not my own.